# What does the `Key` Data Annotation do in database first?

Tags: entity-framework, data-annotations, dto, data-transfer-objects

Everything I find through Google refers to Code First so I'm wondering what the `Key` attribute is actually doing in regards to a Database First design? I'm mainly curious because a lot of the entities contain composite keys so I've been adding the `Key` annotation to the respective properties, but is this really necessary? And if so, what do I gain from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the database-first workflow (i.e. you have an .edmx file in your solution). Then the `Key` attribute will have no effect.

However, if you're using the code-first workflow to map to an existing database, the `Key` attribute tells code first that that property is part of the entity's primary key.

For more info on the different workflows see this video: [Visual Studio Toolbox: Entity Framework Part 1](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Visual-Studio-Toolbox-Entity-Framework-Part-1)

Comment: Thanks! I was curious if it provided any kind of error/constraint checking but it looks like its really only for the Code First workflow.

Comment: While the Key attribute has no effect, attributes that inherit from `ValidationAttribute` (e.g. `Required` and `StringLength`) do get validated on `SaveChanges()` (for all workflows).